# JS: after creating new element and assigning it to a variable, it gives me null

Tags: javascript

Despite the code is working, i just want to understand why it gives me this error.
After clicking the buttons, when i try to call the variable "home", the console tells me it's "null". Why?

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var botoes = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var home = document.getElementById("home");


for(var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
  botoes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    shrink();
    if(botoes[3]) {
    }  else {
        createButton();
      }
  });
}


function shrink() {
  menu.style.margin = "10px";
  menu.style.width = "140px";
}


function createButton() {
  var newButton = document.createElement("button"); //creates button element
  var newButtonText = document.createTextNode("home"); //creates a text node
  newButton.appendChild(newButtonText); //appends the text to button
  var insertButton = menu.appendChild(newButton); //append button to body
  insertButton.className = "botoes"; //adds class to button
  newButton.id = "home"; //adiciona um id ao botao recentemente criado
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise how exactly do you 'call' a variable home? Give us the code that you use to get the null, everything here doesn't point to the issue you have

Comment: Because `home` was initialised, and has had the value `null` since, before you created the button.

Comment: I have a list of buttons in html. When any button is clicked for the first time, it generates a new button. in the beginning of the code i assigned a varible to this new element. I called it "home". When i put "home" in console, shouldn't it give me the new button?

Comment: @Bergi but after creation of the button, shouldn't it have a new value?

Comment: @fields No. The `home` variable gets a new value only when you assign to it. Just like in `var x = 2, y = x+3` the `y` won't get a new value when `x` changes.

Comment: @fields no because 1) an element with an ID is not directly the same as a JS variable. You could have called that variable `dkjhfkjghkjd` if you wanted, it's not related to the element ID. 2) `var home = document.getElementById("home");` implies an element with ID "home" already exists. Then in createButton you create another element with the same ID. Duplicate IDs are invalid (because it's an ID, so it must be unique, otherwise what would be its purpose?). So even if creating a new element with id "home" _did_ have anything to do with a JS variable of the same name, it would still be invalid.

Comment: ok, got it. Thank you for the explanations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did

```
var home = document.getElementById("home");
```

but if the document wasn't loaded yet, the home variable would equate to null as there would be no home element

I think the most relevant thing to take away is to add:

```
home = newButton
```

which actually switches the variables

If the home button already exists, wrap your logic in a onload function:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  var botoes = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var home = document.getElementById("home");


  for(var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
    botoes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      shrink();
      if(botoes[3]) {
      }  else {
          createButton();
        }
    });
  }


  function shrink() {
    menu.style.margin = "10px";
    menu.style.width = "140px";
  }


  function createButton() {
    var newButton = document.createElement("button"); //creates button element
    var newButtonText = document.createTextNode("home"); //creates a text node
    newButton.appendChild(newButtonText); //appends the text to button
    var insertButton = menu.appendChild(newButton); //append button to body
    insertButton.className = "botoes"; //adds class to button
    newButton.id = "home"; //adiciona um id ao botao recentemente criado
    // change buttons
    home = newButton;
  }
});
```

then at the end set home to the new button

In case the button isnt created yet, when you manupulate it check it exists:

```
if (home) {
  // continue
}
```

Comment: This will still return null. you called `var home = document.getElementById("home")` before the createButton function which creates the element!

Comment: Please note that the only relevant change here is `home = newButton` the 'load' eventlistener is not needed to get the effect achieved by this code.
You could just as well call the for loop first and the `document.getElementById("home")` after that. But the point is the misunderstanding by @fields of how JS is executed

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is executed in order it is written.
Meaning the moment your javascript loads it will execute:

```
var home = document.getElementById("home");
```

At that point the element with the `home` id isn't created yet.
Resulting in the home variable being `null`.

Later on when you call it again it hasn't been changed yet, therefor returning you `null`.

If you would call `document.getElementById("home")` in your console it would however return your created element.

After your comment:

I think you misunderstand how your Javascript is called.
You do not reference the `document.getElementById("home")` function to the `home` variable, what you do is get the value returned by the function and keep that in your variable. Which at that point happens to be `null`.

Comment: let's imagine `var test; // it gives undefined`, but later i declare it `var test = 123;` now, if i call test it shoud give me "123". Right? But after the button is created, shouldn't home exist already?

Comment: @fields yes it would. But your code doesn't do that in regards to "home". See my comment above. A JS variable and an element with an ID are not linked based on a matching ID / variable-name. I think you have mis-understood how JS works.

Comment: Exactly what @ADyson says. The variable value is copied, not pointed towards the element.